# How to rename automatically image file names while uploading?

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading, file-rename

Here's my upload function code:

```
function upload(&$file, $destinationDir = "", $destinationName = "", $secure = true){
    $ret = false;
    if (isset($file['tmp_name']) && isset($file['name'])){
        if ($destinationName == ''){
            $destinationName = $file['name'];
        }

        $destinationFile = $destinationDir . '/' . $destinationName;
        if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $destinationFile)){
            if ($secure){
                chmod($destinationFile, 0644);
            }

            $ret = true;
        }
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

This function can't rename file names automatically, if two files name are same, it will replace new image file to existing file.

How can I change this above function to rename files automatically while uploading to server?

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried changing `$destinationName` to something other than `$file['name']`?

Comment: Rename to what exactly? Tip: Using `sha1_file()` to generate a filename is a pretty good idea.

Comment: @deceze - why not [tempnam](http://php.net/tempnam) which exists exactly for such purposes? No need to fiddle too much, let the OS do its job ^.^

Comment: @Mjh Because you don't want to generate a *temporary file* or even a file in the tmp directory, but a *permanent* name. Also, using the hash as a name gives you trivial deduplication.

Comment: it doesn't matter, just rename file names, I mean new image files won't replace to existing files. this is what I want.

Comment: @deceze so if I got you right, it's better to hash the entire contents of the file to get a name (even though you get collisions if you upload the same file a few times), instead of using a function whose purpose is to generate unique file names in the OS's filesystem. Even though the function is badly named, it's very well documented (especially the **unique file name** part) and rarely used and it has nothing to do with temporary files :)

Comment: @Mjh I'd consider the collisions to be a feature, not a bug! For a general purpose file storage solution, deduplicating content is a pretty good feature. Why store the exact same bits twice?

Comment: @deceze - because humans do silly things and aren't logical beings (mistakes happen all the time, you're probably very well aware of it). You can get a collision even if the contents isn't the same. I believe it's the best to let the OS come up with the unique file name and save the human from bullet in the foot (or other bad things).

Comment: @Mjh Producing a collision with SHA1 is so extremely unlikely as to not be worth considering in the real world.

Comment: @deceze - not walking through a mine-field is better than walking through a field where the chance of a mine is minimal, yet possible.

Comment: @Mjh I think I'd choose the field that deduplicates my mines for me instead of stocking the same mine many many times. Man, this analogy becomes strained. Again, collisions are so unlikely as to not be worth considering. Understanding and using probabilities can free you up to some more interesting architectures. If I was really worried about them, I'd add another layer of double checking the contents of the file should I encounter a duplicate; but I'm not worried about this so I won't.

Comment: @deceze - I could have asked the question in a different way - why hash anything if you don't have to? Why more work if you don't have to? What if you have to hash a 1.5GB file? Is the hashing solution really the best possible option? I could think of a few more reasons why file hash is a bad decision and why letting OS worry about file naming is better. Anyway, I posted the alternative, people are always free to use whatever they deem fit. You think hash is the way to go, I don't, we agree to disagree. I suggest we stop here, it doesn't appear this discussion is going anywhere.

Comment: @Mjh Hashing a 1.5GB file takes just about 7 seconds for me. If your system allows uploads of 1+GB files, then a) 7 seconds of post-processing time is perfectly reasonable and b) you should be all the more interested in deduplicating your storage. Sure, I'm perfectly happy to concede that you may have your reasons for not wanting to use hashes, I'm not trying to say that it's the perfect choice for everyone every time. However, if you criticise the approach, the criticism has to be valid.

Comment: @deceze - and how is my criticism not valid? You can have a collision, even though unlikely. You can spend time calculating the hash *just in order to obtain a unique file name*. You can purposely upload the same file a few times (why not, perfectly valid use case), why would you deduplicate anything? The sole reason I'm criticising the hash approach is because it's the wrong tool for the job. The correct tool exists, is built into the OS, works fast, is accurate and implementation is even easier than the hash approach.

Comment: @Mjh Well, agree to disagree then, really. As for "right tool for the job" and "it's the OS' job"... `tempnam`'s job is to generate a temporary filename **you don't care about**. I'd argue that you *should care about* the filenames of your storage system. It's not the OS' job to come up with file names for all your files in general, it's just its job to *store* them reliably under a given key. Filenames are keys for data, and there are situations in which you care about the key, and cases where you don't, and cases where the key generation process is important and useful for its properties.

Comment: @deceze - the function's purpose is to **generate a unique file name in the file system**.  What you *care* about is to store the file in a safe way and to have the name you can use to refer to it. You get **exactly** that. What the file name is is completely irrelevant, much like in the case when the name == the hash. What's relevant is to get a reference to the file, while working in concurrent environment. The OS's job is to let you have that. There is absolutely no way you can do that better than the OS can. That's why I said the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Mjh Again, keys/file names *can* have more and different properties than just storing a file in the file system, and using these properties can be useful. Generating the name based on its contents allows you unique global identification of a piece of data, even across systems; using UUIDs for example practically guarantees you global uniqueness of the name and no collisions ever across any system you'll ever encounter... If these specific properties are desirable to you then you should use them. If you don't, then just let the OS choose an arbitrary name for you, fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the extension:

```
//Get extension
$ext = pathinfo($file["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Then change this line:

```
$destinationName = $file['name'];
```

to a combination of the `sha1` hash of the file appended to the timestamp, with the extension:

```
$destinationName = sha1_file($file["tmp_name"]).time().".".$ext;
```

Comment: I did it, but if file name is test.jpg, it will change name to something like this test.jpg1446651332

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Why add `time()` into the mix here? Using just the hash to ***deduplicate*** stored files is one of the great advantages here.

Comment: For all we know there *could* be an occasion where two people upload the *same* file...

Comment: Exactly. Why'd you store the same bits twice?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
$destionationFile = $destinationDir . '/' . $destinationName; 
if(is_file($destinationFile))
{
$destinationName = basename($destinationName).'_'.hash('sha256', time().rand(9999, 999999)).'.'.pathinfo($destinationName)['extension'];
$destionationFile = $destinationDir . '/' . $destinationName;
}
```

Comment: What if the same file (same name) is uploaded twice within the same second? *Unlikely*, granted, but not impossible. The more popular your site the more likely it becomes.

Comment: Meh.......... you've made it *even less likely*, yes; this will probably be fine in practice. However, you should *really* be using actual randomness instead of this strenuous incremental adding of entropy. UUIDs for example, for `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`.